# List the files and folder within a folder in google cloud storage using JSON API

Tags: json, google-cloud-storage

I know Google Cloud Storage doesn't manage folders, but let say I have this file:

mybucket/documentation/user

and I want all files that are within documentation/user but not those under documentation/user/version1/ or documentation/user/version2/

I want to see that under documentation/user there are 2 files (version1/ and version2/) but I don't want to get the files within recursive folders.

Is it possible using the JSON API? I know the concept of delitimer. But it only works on the root of the bucket. If I use the / as delimiter on the root I get al folders and files within the root of the bucket, but when I use the prefix documentation/user with delimiter "/" I get an empty list :-(

Comment: Have you tried prefix of `documentation/user/`? Note the trailing slash.

Comment: the trailing slash makes no difference :-(

Comment: delimiter=`/` and prefix=`documentation/user/` should definitely work. Try exploring with the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list).

Comment: I am using the form at: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list and when using what you say, @jterrace , I get a 200 OK but a list whith only one entry: "name": "documentation/user/" But there are two folders whithin it :-?

Comment: OK now I see it. You are right @jterrace but the folders get in the "prefixes" attributes of the JSON response, instead of the "items". In the "items" I have all items with prefix documentation/user/ but I guess I can ask only for the field "prefixes". Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624900/jterrace), using

```
delimiter = /
```

and

```
prefix = documentation/user/
```

should get you what you want. Note : the folders will not return in the "items" portion of your JSON response, but in the "prefixes" field. (that part was taken from the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019255/oscar-serrano))

Answer (score 1):

Here's the generic rule -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/{bucket}/o?prefix={URL Encoded Name of the object}
```

In the above case it would be -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/{bucket}/o?prefix=document%2Fuser/
```

The delimiter '/' is used to contain the search result within the prefix. If no delimiter is used then all the children node are also searched and the result is returned.